# How to move MariaDB database directories between instances safely

Tags: mariadb

Consider the situation where you have two MariaDB instances (perhaps on different physical servers), each with a different data_dir.

The first instance has DATA_DIR1, containing folders for InnoDB databases DB1 and DB2

The second instance has DATA_DIR2, containing folders for InnoDB databases DB3 and DB4

Let's say you wanted to move DB2 from the first instance to the second instance.

How could the files be copied between instances safely (i.e. not by doing a mysqldump, which would be too slow for a very large database). Alternatively, using mariabackup partial backups would be an option, since that would not be as slow as mysqldump.

In particular, what needs to be done to properly instruct the first instance that it will no longer see DB2, and to properly instruct the second instance that it should now be recognizing the copy of DB2 that has been placed in DATA_DIR2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first instance, type `SHOW CREATE DATABASE DB2`. For every table inside DB2, type `SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME>`.

Use the output of those commands to recreate the database and (empty) tables inside the second database instance.

On the second instance, for each table in the DB2 database, type `ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DISCARD TABLESPACE;`

On the first instance, for every table in DB2, type `FLUSH TABLES <TABLE_NAME>,<TABLE_NAME>,... FOR EXPORT;`

Copy the files from the DB2 directory in the first instance to the DB2 directory in the second instance.

On the first instance, type `UNLOCK TABLES`.

On the second instance, for each table in the database type  `ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transportable-tablespace-internals.html

Answer (score 0):

*No* the files cannot be copied, at least not as-is.

Look into "transportable tablespaces", if it is available in your version.  That preps the files for being copies.